# Modify .TIF and then export it as .ASC with Rasterio several times

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff, rasterio, esri-ascii-raster

First time asking here in Gis StackExchange. I'm working with a .tif file that I read with rasterio, then I take its values as a numpy array and then I have to modify it several times. I can do that without problem, but I wasn't able to export it as a .asc (neither a .tif). I think I don't know which driver and transformation I have to choose.

I attach my code until this moment:

```py
import numpy as np
import rasterio

tif_raster = rasterio.open("RGB2.byte.tif")
raw_array = tif_raster.read(1)

# Modify array
value = 50
new_array  = np.where( (raw_array != 0) & (raw_array <= value) , 1, 0)

# Export array
new_tif = rasterio.open(
    "new_raster.asc",
    "w",
    driver="GTiff",
    height=new_array.shape[0],
    width=new_array.shape[1],
    count=1,
    dtype=new_array.dtype,
    crs=tif_raster.crs,
    transform=tif_raster.transform
)
```

But I'm just getting an empty file.

I'm using [this](https://github.com/rasterio/rasterio/blob/main/tests/data/RGB2.byte.tif) file as an example here.

Comment: You need to specify the new driver, try setting the driver for new_raster.asc as `AAIGrid` . Gotten from here https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/aaigrid.html

Comment: In addition to the above comment, you'll need to actually write to the file you've opened: https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#saving-raster-data

Comment: I see, thank you so much both of you!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Shawn and @mikewatt. Here is the final code

```py
import numpy as np
import rasterio

tif_raster = rasterio.open("RGB2.byte.tif")
raw_array = tif_raster.read(1)

# Modify array
value = 50
new_array  = np.where( (raw_array != 0) & (raw_array <= value) , 1, 0)
with rasterio.open(
    'new_raster.asc',
    'w',
    driver='AAIGrid',
    height=new_array.shape[0],
    width=new_array.shape[1],
    count=1,
    dtype=new_array.dtype,
    crs=tif_raster.crs,
    transform=tif_raster.transform,
    force_cellsize=True
) as dst:
    dst.write(new_array, 1)
```

I had to add `force_cellsize=True` since the original file doesn't have a fix cellsize.